# HTML5 Semantic mark up help

Tags: html, markup, semantic-markup

I'm just starting a new app. Below is a basic mockup of what I am tasked to do. 
I'm new to using HTML5 for my semantic markup so I'd like some feedback/help.

I'd like to understand how/where to use things like `<nav>` and `<section>`

```
<div id="container">
    <header>

    <div id="appInformation">
      <a href="#" alt="Home">
        <img src="">
      </a>

      <span>Selected AppName</span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <span id="time">TIME GOES HERE</span>
    </div>

    <div>
      <a href="#" alt="Additional Information">
        <img src=""><!-- This is will be the location of the the 'i'-->
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="">
      <label>UserName</label>
    </div>  

    </header>
    <div id="main">
        <!-- main content for the selected app here -->
    </div>

    <footer>

        <div id="appVersion">
            VERSION # HERE
        </div>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">FAQ</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div id="">
            <!-- Team logo here-->
        </div>

    </footer>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Avoid unacessary Div.
- Use the Time Tag instead of Div for Time Element.
- Avoid Label if you don't have anything to refer too, like an input.

  Selected AppName

  ```
      <time datetime="YYYY-MM-DD">TIME GOES HERE</time><!--  Don't need an id Time since you can target the Time tag -->

      <a href="#" alt="Additional Information">
          <img src=""><!-- This is will be the location of the the 'i'-->
      </a>

      <em>UserName</em> <!-- Don't use a label if you got nothing to refer too, like an input for example. -->
  </header>
  <div id="main">
      <!-- main content for the selected app here -->
  </div>
  <footer>
      <div id="appVersion">
          VERSION # HERE
      </div>
      <nav>
          <ul>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">FAQ</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </nav>

      <a href="yourTeamUrl" id="">
          <!-- Team logo here-->
      </a>
  </footer>
  ```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Simon Arnold's fine answer, I might also suggest that the `<nav>` usage is incorrect. A single link in a footer can hardly be construed as a "major navigation block". See the first note in green text at http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/sections.html#the-nav-element

Comment: There will probably be like 3-4 links which might grow slightly over time. If that is the case does this change things?

Comment: That's really a judgement call. If you consider the set of links to be a major navigation block for your site then it's OK to use it. However, it would be most unusual for a major navigation block to be in a `<footer>` so consider moving it out of there. You can still place it at the bottom of your page if that the styling you want, but semantically it seems an unlikely arrangement.

Comment: Yeah I agree its certainly not a major nav block at all.